# Spark Elasticsearch connector fails to parse date as date. They are parsed as Long

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elastic-stack

I am pushing HDFS parquet Data to ElasticSearch using ES spark connector.
I have two columns having dates that I am unable to parse as date. They keep being ingested as long. They have the following formats:

- basic_ordinal_date: YYYYddd
- epoch_millis: in milliseconds; e.g. 1555498747861

I tried the following

- Defining ingest pipelines
- Defining mappings
- Defining dynamic mappings
- Defining index_templates with mapping
- Converting my date columns to string so Elastic does some pattern matching

Depending on the method, either I have errors and my Spark job fails, or the documents are pushed with the concerned columns that remain parked as long.

How should I proceed to have my ordinal_dates, epoch_millis parsed as dates ?
Thank you in advance for your help